# How to make an application, that is able to scan barcode from the image of the Barcode which is taken from the sdcard of the android mobile itself?

Tags: java, android, barcode, zxing

My Requirement is, after opening the application there will be a button which will open the camera application and takes picture of the two barcodes then that bitmap will be given to my application and the barcode decoder will decode that two barcodes and displays result !!
Is it possible?
if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible.

There are a lot of barcode decoding libraries like https://github.com/zxing/zxing/ 
Integrate the library, follow its tutorial and pass the bitmap to it. Then after decoding display the result.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i have downloaded this source code and i have also import it to my android studio it displays so much error, then i have solve all the errors and run the application but it is the same application which is there on the play store and it doesn't provide this kind of functionality , my question is how to implement zing in my project and provide this kind of functionality !

Answer (score 0):

You Can, Try [MultiFormatReader](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/MultiFormatReader.html) from ZXing Librery

Sample Code

```
try
{
    InputStream inputStream = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    if (bitmap == null)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "uri is not a bitmap," + uri.toString());
        return null;
    }
    int width = bitmap.getWidth(), height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
    RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(width, height, pixels);
    BinaryBitmap bBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
    MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
    try
    {
        Result result = reader.decode(bBitmap);
        return result;
    }
    catch (NotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "decode exception", e);
        return null;
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "can not open file" + uri.toString(), e);
    return null;
}
```